# Struct with const element is not trivial?

Tags: c++, c++11

Regarding the following code, I understand that the structure B does not have a default constructor even after removing the comment marks.  Hence, the first static assertion fails. I also understand that the second static assertion does not fail "by definition".

```
struct B
{
    const int value;
    // B() = default;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert( std::is_trivially_constructible<B>::value, "B should be trivially constructible" );
    static_assert( std::is_trivially_constructible<const int>::value, "const int should be trivially constructible" );
}
```

However, I reason that the structure and the enclosed constant integer are "basically the same" when it comes to the steps that it would take to construct them. I am led to the conclusion that 'std::is_trivially_constructible' does not reflect "the steps taken to create an object".

Do you have a mental picture to replace mine ( where 'is_trivially_constructible' is tied to how the object can be created ) ?

Comment: I don't think the second should succeed either, as a `const` primitive needs to be initialized or else have indeterminate value forever.

Comment: Given that `B` has no default-constructor, the expression `B()` is ill-formed whereas with `using T = const int;`, `T()` is not ill-formed. That's the difference `is_trivially_constructible` is pointing out. (I.e. `std::is_constructible<B>::value == false`)

Comment: @dyp: That's value-initialization, right?

Comment: @dyp g++ 4.8.3 accepts `B();` (but not `B b;`) , is that a compiler bug?

Comment: @MattMcNabb [g++4.9 rejects this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27f99fee8c8b6e75); and yes I think g++4.8.3's behaviour is a bug. IIRC there's been a defect related to some combination of `const` and initialization, but I can't remember the details.

Comment: @BenVoigt `B()` is value-intitialization. I think `is_constructible` uses value-init, too: `is_constructible` is defined via `T t( std::forward<Args>(args)... )` and `Args` is an empty pack here, so we're left with a `T t()` that isn't parsed as a function declaration. But for class types w/o default ctor, value initialization *is* default initialization.

Comment: The definition for `is_trivially_constructible` here is that if we have  function definition `T && create();` then the line `T t ( create() );` must not do any non-trivial operations

Comment: Well that suggests a better name for the metafunction/trait...

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't know where you've seen that, but in C++11 as well as n3797, it's defined as `is_constructible` plus requirements on the variable definition used to define `is_constructible`. That trait is defined via `T t ( create<Args>()... )`, not via move construction. In our case, `Args` is an empty type parameter pack, so it's defined as `T t ()` (not a function declaration), as I said earlier.

Comment: @BenVoigt What do you mean? A better name for which trait?

Comment: @dyp this was from N3337, I guess it changed between that and C++11

Comment: @MattMcNabb Even in n3337, I find in Table 49 the condition for `is_trivially_constructible<T, Args...>`: "`is_constructible<T, Args...>::value` is `true` and the variable definition for `is_constructible`, as defined below, is known to call no operation that is not trivial." An in [meta.unary.prop]/6 I find the `template<class T> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();` and `T t(create<Args>()...)` (where `Args` is from `is_constructible<T, Args...>`).

Comment: @dyp `typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type` is `T&&` when `T` is not already a reference type (as in this case)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, but `T && create();` and `T t ( create() );` is still not correct. The two `T`s are unrelated, and the expression inside the `()` of the initialization of `t` is a pack expansion. This is important here since it's an empty pack. In my opinion, your comment suggests that a move construction is involved.

Comment: So you're saying that `create<` *blank* `>()...` actually means *blank*, not `create()` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, for `sizeof...(Args) == 0`, `T t( create<Args>()... )` is `T t( )`, but not a function declaration as it would be when you explicitly write `T t ()`. Just like for `Args = int, double`, `T t( create<Args>()... )` is essentially the same as `T t( int{}, double{} )` for purposes of checking if that's valid. If you notify me with `@dyp`, I might respond sooner.

Comment: @dyp OK. The text "These tokens are never interpreted as a function declaration" is a bit naff, because if the tokens have a different meaning to what those tokens mean in C++ then we'd need a specification of that meaning. I guess it is clear enough what the intent was, but it makes it hard to test out via code: e.g. you cannot test your compiler's implementation of `is_trivially_constructible` by seeing if `T t();` compiles.  Is there any reason they did not specify `T t {}` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well that sentence is a non-normative note. I suppose that there's another place in the Standard where it's strictly defined what `T t ( pack-expansion )` means if the pack is empty. Defining `is_constructible` via `{}` is not possible, list-initialization is different from non-list-initialization. For example, a `std::vector<int>` cannot be constructed from 5 `int`s using `std::vector<int> t(1,2,3,4,5)`, but it can be constructed using `std::vector<int> t{1,2,3,4,5}`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That `T t ()` is a function-declaration is a property of the *grammar*, so that doesn't apply to `T t (empty-pack-expansion)`. And in general, the meaning of initializing `T` from an empty set of parentheses is defined in [dcl.init]/10